# SQL query: I need to SELECT all entries matching string AND the last row entry for each DateTime in a log

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find all Login/Logged Out/Session Expired entries in a log AND the LAST entry for each Date in the same log.

A snippet of my Data looks like this:

```
"DateTime"  "Action"  
"12/27/2018 12:04 PM" "Logged Out. Logged in for 240 minutes" 
"12/27/2018 12:10 PM" "Login Successful" 
"12/27/2018 12:10 PM" "Patient Search" 
"12/27/2018 12:41 PM" "Logged Out. Logged in for 89.8 minutes" 
"12/27/2018 3:06 PM" "Login Successful" 
"12/27/2018 3:30 PM" "Viewed All"
```

I'm able to find the "Login/Logged Out/Session Expired" entries using the code below; But I am struggling on how to select the last row for each Date as well.
ie. Output should be:

```
"DateTime"  "Action"  
"12/27/2018 12:04 PM" "Logged Out. Logged in for 240 minutes" 
"12/27/2018 12:10 PM" "Login Successful" 
"12/27/2018 12:41 PM" "Logged Out. Logged in for 89.8 minutes" 
"12/27/2018 3:06 PM" "Login Successful" 
"12/27/2018 3:30 PM" "Viewed All" 


SELECT *
            FROM LOGS WITH (NOLOCK) 
              WHERE [Username] = '",username,"' 
              AND (Action LIKE 'Login S%' OR Action LIKE 'Logged%' OR 
              Action LIKE '%session%') 
              AND [DateTime] BETWEEN '",From_date,"' AND '",To_date,"'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear.  This is an SQL query (more efficient for me).  But a solution in R would work as well.

Comment: You can still edit your question, also by last row for each date means the last action made in each date?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql). Also, make sure your sample data contains all relevant columns, and if you want the last record for each date, be sure to include multiple dates in your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Your query implies there is a 3rd field (UserName) in your data. If you're looking to find the "oldest" entry for a username, I'd explore using a subquery with a "GROUP BY" username, and the aggregate function MAX on the datetime, then you can JOIN the subquery values back into your initial query.